# How can I tell which files vscode is including in its workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode with a moderately large code repo on linux.  The repo area itself has 30K files or so.  In vscode, I include /inc and various normal system libraries.  Vscode claims to be looking over almost 9M files in the workspace (according to "parsing workspace files..." message).  Is this actually possible?  Is there a way to see the files listed out somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working in ssh with the remote extension, so the path may be a little different if you are working natively.

I had the same question, so I looked in ~/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage//ms-vscode.cpptools/.browse.VC.db

This a sqlite3 database, which I explored with sqlitestudio_x64-3.4.3, and I was able to find the entries of the files parsed by Intellisense, in the "files" Tables.
(Right clic, 'Edit the table', 'Data' tab).